# Postgresql storage on K3s

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, k3s

I am trying to setup a Postgresql Stateful-Set on a k3s single node (Raspberry Pi 4 8Gb) cluster which will be common between any services that end up needing postgresql. Currently, since this is just a single node, I am using the Rancher `local-path` storage provisioner (this will probably change as I add nodes) pointing to an external hdd set to mount, though this will probably change when I get around to adding nodes.

My pod spins up (after figuring out a small headache with mounting the data directory which was as per [this](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/116) issue), and I can access the postgresql instance with `kubectl port-forward -n common pod/postgresql-stateful-set-0 5432:5432`, and making whatever changes I need.

At this point, my problem manifests, whereby I notice that no data is persisted in my data directory. I have found [this](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/696) issue which is the exact issue I've encountered, but following all the examples of "fixes", from playing with the directory locations (which gave me `chmod` issues like encountered with the mounting data directory issues), to changing to a `pv` I defined.

Find below my yml file which is use `kubectl apply -f postgres.yml` and is based on the `bitnami` helm template:

```
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: postgresql-storage
provisioner: rancher.io/local-path
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgresql-pv
  namespace: common
spec:
  storageClassName: postgresql-storage
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/storage/k3s/common/postgresql"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  namespace: common
  name: pvc-postgresql
spec:
  storageClassName: postgresql-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgresql-password
  namespace: common
data:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <PWD>
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgresql-configmap
  namespace: common
data:
  POSTGRESQL_PORT_NUMBER: "5432"
  PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgresql-stateful-set
  namespace: common
  labels:
    name: postgres-stateful-set
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: postgresql-stateful-set
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate: {}
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgresql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgresql
          image: docker.io/postgres:14.2-alpine
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: postgresql-configmap
          - secretRef:
              name: postgresql-password
          ports:
            - name: tcp-postgresql
              containerPort: 5432
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 6
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - exec pg_isready -U "rootAdmin" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d rootDefault
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 6
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - -e
                - exec pg_isready -U "rootAdmin" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d rootDefault
          resources:
            limits: 
              memory: "300Mi"
              cpu: "300m"
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 256Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: dshm
              mountPath: /dev/shm
            - name: postgresql-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
      volumes:
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: postgresql-data
      spec:
        storageClassName: postgresql-storage
        accessModes:
          - "ReadWriteOnce"
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: "20Gi"
---
kind: Service 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: postgresql-svc
  namespace: common
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgresql
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: tcp-postgresql
      port: 5432
      protocol: TCP
```

---

Couple of things I should probably mention:

- I added my own Storage class for the purposes of retaining the record rather then delete on the record being removed.
- using the alpine version just for the sake of smaller image size.
- The base OS that k3s is hosted on is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- K3s was setup using this ansible playbook [here](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s-ansible)
- I have `exec`-ed into the container to see what is in the directory defined by `PGDATA` and confirmed that data was written.